# Custom cells of uitableview are not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using a `tableview` with `custom cell`.

My custom `cell` has got label and I have defined its `outlet` at 'StatutoryMappingCell.h'

Following isn `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
StatutoryMappingCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if (!cell)
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"KnowledgeMainCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}

return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(StatutoryMappingCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.statMapping.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The problem is that the `cells` are not visible when I run my code. But the  Why is that so?

This is my xib scene...
[image]

This is my storyboard scene

[image]

Comment: are you using storyboard or xib

Comment: are you declared the number of rows in section

Comment: what is name of the nib file

Comment: Name of nib file is KnowledgeMainCell

Comment: I have declared numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I using xib for my custom cell.......

Comment: have u set file owner of the xib file

Comment: what is the number of sections and rows in tableView, if you give `numberOfRowsInSection` method, if you get the row value is zero, does not call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, please check it

Comment: The method you are using is deprecated.  Use the correct method and make sure you have registered the nib with the table view.  You will have more correct code, and less of it.

Comment: Use the Xcode debugger. Step through your code and check if the correct number of rows are being used and if the cells are being allocated. Your code is odd though - I would expect the XIB to be `alloc/`init`ed rather than dequeued in your `nil` check section. I suggest you move to custom cells in the Storyboard TableView rather than using a XIB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your interface builder - you shuld have not `conntected` your custom cell, you should set it as a `files owner` , if yes check once the labels are connected or not,

Comment: Should i set the file owner as parent class where Im loading tableview datas or child class where I have linked the custom cell labels?

Comment: see this link it guides you https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722#.5lw8nqore , http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/ios-custom-uitableviewcell-example.html

Comment: my cell is xib file while the viewcontroller containing tableview is at storyboard

Comment: I have added the screen shots bro

Comment: y u take the xib , you can handle with prototype cells , it is easy and optimized bro

Comment: why because i will have to add two more labels to each of my cells

Answer (score 0):

try these code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"identifier";
   CellItemList *cellA = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cellA == nil)
   {
       // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:(isIpad)?@"CellItemList~ipad":@"CellItemList" owner:self options:nil];
      // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
      cellA = (CellItemList *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
   }
 cellA.statMapping.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cellA;
}
```

Comment: still its not visible

Comment: are you set tableview delegate?

Comment: try using remove identifier from myCell xib

Comment: I have set the delegate

Comment: I tried removing the identifier but still the same problem